# Validating image's aspect ratio (width/height) with Yup & formik

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I am trying to do the validation using yup for image file, what I found was https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/926 which only validates the size and also the file type.

and this one is the current yup validation that I use

```js
file: lazy(value => {
    switch (typeof value) {
      case 'string':
        return string().required(errorHandler.requiredFile());
      default:
        return mixed()
          .required(errorHandler.requiredFile())
          .test(
            'fileSize',
            'Size',
            value => value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE
          )
          .test(
            'fileType',
            'Format',
            value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)
          )
    }
  }),
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using this function

```js
function checkAspectRatio(value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value);
    reader.onload = function(value) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = value.target.result;
      img.onload = function() {
        const aspectRatio = this.width / this.height;
        resolve(aspectRatio);
      };
    };
  });
}
```

using `Object.defineProperty()` to define a new property on the object

```js
Object.defineProperty(file, 'aspectRatio', {
  value: await checkAspectRatio(file)
});
```

and test the value using yup

```js
.test(
  'fileAspectRatio',
  'Please recheck the image resolution',
  value => value && value.aspectRatio === 1.6
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It saved me.

Comment: Hi there, how do you do the "Define a new property on the object" part? I cant seem to do this when the file is uploaded using an onClick on an input with type "file"

Comment: @alexr89 make sure the object on which to define the property exists and then you can modify it

Answer (score 3):

1. create a promise that will load the image file and return the dimension

```
const imageWidthAndHeight = (provideFile) => {
    // take the given file (which should be an image) and return the width and height
    const imgDimensions = { width: null, height: null };

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(provideFile);
        reader.onload = function () {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = reader.result;

            img.onload = function () {
                imgDimensions.width = img.width;
                imgDimensions.height = img.height;

                resolve(imgDimensions);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

2. Call and await promise within a custom yup function (using addMethod) and add additional validation to check width and height.

```
const imageDimensionCheck = Yup.addMethod(Yup.mixed, 'imageDimensionCheck', function (message, requiredWidth, requiredHeight) {
    return this.test("image-width-height-check", message, async function (value) {
        const { path, createError } = this;

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        const imgDimensions = await imageWidthAndHeight(value);

        if (imgDimensions.width !== requiredWidth) {
            return createError({
                path,
                message: `The file width needs to be the ${requiredWidth}px!`
              });
        }

        if (imgDimensions.height !== requiredHeight) {
            return createError({
                path,
                message: `The file height needs to be the ${requiredHeight}px!`
              });
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

3. Call the created Yup method within formik

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        bookCoverPhoto: null,
    }}

    validationSchema={
        Yup.object().shape({
            bookCoverPhoto: Yup.mixed()
                .required('You need to provide a file')
                .imageDimensionCheck('test', 1988, 3056)
        })
    }
>
....Stuff
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image: Yup.mixed()
  .required("Image is required.")
  .test(
    "aspectRatio",
    "Aspect ratio must be 16:9",
    value => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(value[0]);
        reader.onload = function(value) {
          const img = new Image();
          img.src = value.target.result;
          img.onload = function() {
            const aspectRatio = this.width / this.height;
            resolve(aspectRatio === (16 / 9));
          };
        };
      });
    }
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative method that are faster than (de)encoding to/from base64 and dose not need the filereader

```js
function checkAspectRatio (file) {
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    return img.decode().then(() => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
        return img.width / img.height
    })
}

// not as cross compatible
function checkAspectRatio (file) {
    return createImageBitmap(file)
      .then(bitmap => bitmap.width / bitmap.height)
}
```